# RxJavaHooks cannot be resolved in my android unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java

In my android unit testing file, I am doing this import:

> import rx.plugins.RxJavaHooks;

as I need to use RxJavaHooks.

In my gradle file, i have added the dependency for RxJava and RxAndroid:

> compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$RXANDROID_VERSION"
>
> compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:$RXJAVA_VERSION"

Still, I get an error that RxJavaHooks cannot be resolved. Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`rx.plugins.RxJavaHooks` is an artifact of RxJava 1.x.

the group part of the coordinates of your dependencies (`io.reactivex`) indicates you are using RxJava 2.x, which is why the class you're looking for isn't available.

(fyi - RxJava 1.x classes uses the `rx` namespace)

according to the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0) you should use `RxJavaPlugins`:

> The class-based RxJavaObservableHook and friends are now gone and
>   RxJavaHooks functionality is incorporated into RxJavaPlugins.